# How to return value based on array inspection + if-statement?

Tags: function, return, arrow-functions

I am getting a warning on the following function

```
function currencySubmenuTitle(ctx) {
    let id = Object.keys(currencies).find(element => {
        if (currencies[element].id === ctx.match[1]) {
             return element
        }
    })
    if (typeof id === 'undefined' || id === null) {
        return "No match found"
    } else {
        return ` ${toTitleCase(id)} : ${currencies[id].current}`
    }
}
```

Note: My id and element are different, so I can't just take the element and use that as the string return.

The warning is:

```
2:51  warning  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return
2:51  warning  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  consistent-return
```

How do I return my value in this function in a compliant way (aka not how I am doing it)
Can I thenify this? Run the if statement based on the return of the array-evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of the statement can happen in the return line, so no specific if-statement is needed here. Simply do:

```
function currencySubmenuTitle(ctx) {
    let id = Object.keys(currencies).find(element => {
        return currencies[element].id === ctx.match[1]
    })
    if (typeof id === 'undefined' || id === null) {
        return "No match found"
    } else {
        return ` ${toTitleCase(id)} : ${currencies[id].current}`
    }
}
```